# Checking a sentence if it is a pangram by using a Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, pangram

I would like to create a case where the user needs the enter a sentence.

The code should validate if the sentence is :

- a pangram
- not a complete pangram
- not a pangram

In the text area: the system should display which option the sentence is.

In the attachment a screenshot of how the JFrame looks like.

Can someone help me with how I can implement this?

[image]

Comment: What's the distinction between "not a complete pangram" and "not a pangram"?  Either a sentence contains all 26 letters of the alphabet or it doesn't.  I'd start by creating the Swing GUI by hand and not using a GIUI builder.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps.  Skip the Netbeans section.  Oh, the word is "sentence".

Comment: Not a complete pangram = at least one letter of the alphabet is enter
Not a pangram = (field is empty or the user have entered number(s)).

It needs to be in Netbeans Jframe because is a task for school.

Comment: What’s the specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

I went ahead and created the following GUI.

[image: Pangram Analysis 1]

The GUI consists of a `JFrame` with one main `JPanel`.  The `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout` and consists of a `JLabel`, `JTextArea`, `JLabel`, `JTextArea`.

The GUI processes the sentence as it's typed by using a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).  The code in the `DocumentListener` is simple since I do the work of processing the sentence in a separate class.

Here's the GUI after I've typed a few characters.

[image: Pangram Analysis 2]

A few more characters

[image: Pangram Analysis 3]

The final result

[image: Pangram Analysis 4]

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

I created one model class, one view class, and one controller class.  The `PangramModel` model class produces a result `String` for any input sentence `String`.  The `PangramGUI` view class creates the GUI.  The `SentenceDocumentListener` controller class updates the result `JTextArea`.

The most complicated code can be found in the model class.  There are probably many ways to process a sentence `String`.  This was the way I coded.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class PangramGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PangramGUI());
    }
    
    private JTextArea sentenceArea;
    private JTextArea resultArea;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pangram Analysis");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Type the sentence to analyze");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        sentenceArea = new JTextArea(3, 40);
        sentenceArea.setLineWrap(true);
        sentenceArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        sentenceArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                new SentenceDocumentListener());
        panel.add(sentenceArea, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Pangram result");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        resultArea = new JTextArea(4, 40);
        resultArea.setEditable(false);
        resultArea.setLineWrap(true);
        resultArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        panel.add(resultArea, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class SentenceDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
        
        private PangramModel model;
        
        public SentenceDocumentListener() {
            this.model = new PangramModel(); 
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            processSentence(sentenceArea.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            processSentence(sentenceArea.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            processSentence(sentenceArea.getText());
        }
        
        private void processSentence(String text) {
            String result = model.processSentence(text);
            resultArea.setText(result);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class PangramModel {
        
        private String alphabet; 
        
        public PangramModel() {
            this.alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        }
        
        public String processSentence(String sentence) {
            int[] count = new int[alphabet.length()];
            
            for (int index = 0; index < sentence.length(); index++) {
                char c = Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(index));
                int charIndex = alphabet.indexOf(c);
                if (charIndex >= 0) {
                    count[charIndex]++;
                }
            }
            
            if (isEmpty(count)) {
                return "Not a pangram";
            } else {
                List<Character> missingCharacters = getUnusedCharacters(count);
                if (missingCharacters.size() <= 0) {
                    return "A pangram";
                } else {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    builder.append("Not a complete pangram");
                    builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    builder.append("Missing characters: ");
                    for (int index = 0; index < missingCharacters.size(); index++) {
                        builder.append(missingCharacters.get(index));
                        if (index < (missingCharacters.size() - 1)) {
                            builder.append(", ");
                        }
                    }
                    return builder.toString();
                }
            }
        }
        
        private boolean isEmpty(int[] count) {
            for (int index = 0; index < count.length; index++) {
                if (count[index] > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        
        private List<Character> getUnusedCharacters(int[] count) {
            List<Character> output = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < count.length; index++) {
                if (count[index] <= 0) {
                    output.add(alphabet.charAt(index));
                }
            }
            
            return output;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gilbert,
Thank you very much for all your work.

Kr, 

Yama

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, you should mark it as answered.